# Find JArray and add JObject

Tags: c#, json.net

How do you find a JArray named "response" and add a New JObject?

```
var json = new JObject();
json.Add(new JProperty("response", new JArray()));

using (var reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        json.GetValue("response").AddAfterSelf( // throws exception
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("id", reader.GetString(0)),
                new JProperty("val", reader.GetString(1))
            )
         );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, always include information about your error. This helps your fellow peers assist you.

The error states that 'JProperty cannot contain multiple values'.

All you need to do is update two lines:

```
json.Add("response", new JArray());  // simplified
```

and

```
((JArray)json.GetValue("response")).Add(
```

The casting of json.GetValue('response') to JArray gives you access to its Add method and fixes the error.

Final Code:

```
var json = new JObject();
json.Add("response", new JArray());

using (var reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        ((JArray)json.GetValue("response")).Add( // <- add cast
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("id", reader.GetString(0)),
                new JProperty("val", reader.GetString(1))
            )
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works, however what you said is not correct (where the problem is). I reformatted your code and used the original `var json = new JObject(new JProperty("response", new JArray()));` and it works. I guess the problem was with the cast, I didn't know where to put it since I'm new to C#, so the .Add method wasn't showing

Comment: Updated answer with the information you provided back.